# Obtain domain from URLs

Tags: mysql

I've recently started using MySQL Workbench for my degree of data and I am currently trying to work out how to obtain the domain from a large variety of URLs.

There is not a relationship in between the URLs and they are quite variable, like:

https://google.es/something/something

http://www.outlook.com/something/something

http://wwww.facebook.com/something/something/something

I am looking to only obtain the domain.__ and remove all the other information.

I tried different ways that I found on this forum but somehow I do not have any success, I would appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('http://a,b,com/foo', '/', 3), '/', -1);
```

-->

```
a.b.com
```

If you need to break things up further, perhaps you need another

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(..., '.', -2)
```

to get

```
b.com
```

However, if you need anything much more complex, then you should think about using a programming language other than SQL, preferably one with good regular expression handling.